# Breeze + OData + MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, breeze, dataservice

I'm trying to use Breeze 1.4.0 with OData for managing data operations against a MS Dynamics CRM 2011 OData service.

Retrieving data works fine, but trying to push data doesn't work. I tried to do a very simple update, but Breeze fails when it reaches the second line:

```js
function updateDeleteMergeRequest(request, aspect, prefix) {
        var extraMetadata = aspect.extraMetadata;
        var uri = extraMetadata.uri;
        if (__stringStartsWith(uri, prefix)) {
            uri = uri.substring(prefix.length);
        }
        request.requestUri = uri;
        if (extraMetadata.etag) {
            request.headers["If-Match"] = extraMetadata.etag;
        }
    }
```

I have debugged through it, and it fails because *aspect.extraMetadata* is undefined. *aspect* is a Breeze Entity.EntityAspect object, which doesn't have that property.

I have also found that the DataServiceVersion used by Breeze for OData is 2.0, while the one for the OData service at MS Dynamics CRM 2011 is 1.0. I'm not sure if that has something to with it. I have also tried to change the DataServiceVersion for Breeze to 1.0.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any MS Dynamic's patch that supports OData 2.0. If not and you are still interested in doing this you could create an OData 1.0 data service adapter but this can be complicated. Another alternative would be to contact Breeze support at  breeze@ideablade.com.  We do build custom adapters for Breeze on a consulting basis.

Comment: As of BreezeJs 1.4.13, available now, the 'extraMetadata' issue has been fixed.  Not sure what other issues you may run into though.

Comment: Also CRM 2015 Update 1 will bring OData v4 to CRM which is much more feature rich. See more here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm/webapipreview)